# AngularJS getting started and manipulating data from database

Tags: angularjs

I'm completely new to `AngularJs`, i literally just spent the whole morning trying to find a good answer to this, but i couldn't. So i hope you guys can help me.

I've seen a lot of the `AngularJs` potential to build faster and better web apps so i decided to start with it. For the moment, i'm working with basics `html, css, jquery` and `php` to build a webpage, get data from database, insert more data, edit, exclude, etc.

My question is: How do i work with `AngularJs` and manipulate the data in the database?

To give an example, let's say i have a client database like this:
[image]

And i want to get this data from my mysql database. How do i do it?

And after that, how can i edit this data and also save it into the database?
For example, let's say i want to change Carl email from `carl@email.com`to `carl_01@email.com`. How to do it?

Basically, before diving deep into this, i want to know if it's possible? how to do it? which language am i going to use? How to get data from db? How to add new data? How to edit an existing data?

I found a lot of tutorials giving examples on how to work with it, but none of them with database interaction.

Hope you guys can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Angular only helps with databinding javascript objects to HTML.  Doing the server-side logic still needs to be done manually.  Although angular's [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is pretty good for the server requests.

Comment: If you are not invested in Angular and want something that can manipulate data (and act as the frontend), take a look a meteor (https://www.meteor.com/).

Comment: Based on your questions, looks like Angular is just a tiny top of the iceberg. You need to learn a lot before you will be able to work on UI. Start with server side technology, decide what language you are going to use: PHP, Ruby, Java, etc. Then learn how to read/write data from database. After that you will be able to crate REST API UI application will consume. And finally you can decide what frontend stack to use.

Comment: @dfsq actually, i already work with html, jquery and php. I already have an webpage working. But instead of changing page to insert a client, then to edit it's data, etc.. I want to use angular to make everything better and faster. But i'm a little confused on how to make the connection with angular (or other similar) and the database (either using php - which i already work with - or other way). Hope i can make explain it better =D

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is only the frontend of your stack.

Your still need a backend that provides angular with methods to read and write data. This could be done by a RESTful webservice (e.g. written in php).

Comment: Yes, but do you have any reference to it? I found a lot of things explaining how to edit the data, etc.. But how to send this change live to the server, or to get this data live from the server, sice php doesn't run live on the front end?

Comment: Google restful and/or ask a new question. Or v try meteor (see comment above)